# black areas in ao map, but normal map looks ok?

Tags: baking

I'm pretty new to baking maps for game assets, so I need some advice.

My settings are : Cycles, selected to active (with cage).
The normal map seems ok to me, but the ao map has really dark areas that I can't explain.

Am I doing something wrong during baking, or is it my mesh (cubes with bevel) ?

[image: normal map of a wall]
[image: ao map of same wall]

Answer (score 2):

Ambient occlusion focuses darkness on the crevices of the model that's why you have those dark areas. If you didn't already know, the ambient occlusion map is usually used to isolate the edges of a model for wear/tear and (if i remember correctly) it is a linear type of map (black and white image)

Comment: More specifically, I was concerned about the black vertical blocks that seem harsh ... Also, I don't see similar structures in the normal map (light info).

Comment: I have done some more research and found this as well: Ambient occlusion shading is determined by the relationships objects and surfaces have to each other, the closer one object is to another, the darker the immediate area surround each due to the way in which their proximity occludes and/or attenuates ambient light. So it could be because of your mesh, and if that's the case:  1) separate objects and/or elements should be joined together into a single contiguous mesh. 2) elements should be positioned relative to final use.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've been trying some more, with cage, without, with baking plane in front/behind of the wall, flipping the baking plane (normals), ... I finally did get an ao bake that looks softer (still not 100% ok), but I have no idea why or how to repeat it. Might be Blender being sensitive (or me being dumb) ... =p